# Will my sins be forgiven

Tags: quran, allah, forgiveness, blessings-of-allah

I have been sinning a lot these days, but now, im truly regretful about it.
I am deeply ashamed of myself, because my sins are really disgusting, so my question is, am i still worthy of forgiveness in the eyes of Allah Azawajal????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As long as you’re completely regretting your acts and aslong as you’re seeking forgiveness of Allah s.w.t sincerely and you make Tawba Allah will completely forgive you.**
Never doubt the mercy of Allah. Make tawba :

- say bismillah, then make niyya (intention to make tawba) and do a perfect wudhu (ablution)
- pray 2 rakats and ask for forgiveness in sujud
- don’t give excuses (Allah knows what and why it happened)
- feel a lot of remorse and regret ; Allah will not forgive you if you don’t feel enough remorse (you can even cry)
- tell Allah you will never repeat it again and be honest.

And remember **Allah is "al-Ghafir" "Ar-Rahman" "Ar-Rahim"** which means He is the most forgiving, the most merciful.
Make Tawba and Allah will forgive you even if you repeated the sin a million times ; aslong as you’re sincere and you regret it.

And Allah s.w.t knows best.