# Committing sins on purpose

Tags: sin, forgiveness

I won’t say the why exactly but I was angry with Allah and some things going on in my life so I stopped praying and I started committing sins on purpose sometimes just to rebel. Will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that answers a similar question pretty well: [Will my sins be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68568/will-my-sins-be-forgiven/68571#68571). Allah will forgive you just don't repeat it, be sincere in your tawba (feel remorse) and promise Allah that you will never do it ever again.