# Major Shirk,Minor Shirk

Tags: sin, shirk, forgiveness

Salam my name is Bilal and i am 12 years old and i have been swearing on my family members like my sisters and my parents and sometimes on allah too like people say i swear but i just learned minor shirk and i am scared that Allah will send me to hell please tell me if i repent Will Allah Forgive me I did not have intentions to commit minor or major shirk and i want to know what are the ways i can repent for it and will my repentance be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Swearing by your family members is a major sin. It's shirk.

You should repent. Here is a good way to repent : [Will my sins be forgiven](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68568/will-my-sins-be-forgiven/68571#68571)

Allah is Al-Ghafur Al-Rahim which means Allah is the Forgiver, the Merciful. He forgives all sins if you repent sincerely.

May Allah forgive us all and grant us all eternal Jannah.

Comment: Thanks but i was talking about you know people say that" i swear in my mom's life ETC this is the one i'm asking is this the one you said isn't shirk?

Comment: It depends. If you meant that your family members are worth as much or more than Allah then it is a major shirk, but if you didn't mean that your family members are important compared to Allah then it's the minor shirk.

Comment: No i didn't intended both..i learned it because i saw that people start to believe that what others  are saying is true for example he says i swear on my mom i didn't steal and the other person is like oh okay he sweared he is not lying" , this has always been my intention..so does this count as shirk? Is it does and i be forgiven if i repent?

Comment: So does that count as shirk or not, cause i did not have intentions to associate partners with Allah in any case

Comment: Please reply i'm scared

Comment: From what I understood yes, it's shirk because a muslim must only swear by Allah, the One who made him, the One who gave him everything he has, the only One capable of everything. Swearing by anyone else is like considering partners to Allah. So you have commited the minor shirk. You will always 100% be forgiven if you repent sincerely. Allah forgives all sins if one repents sincerely.

Comment: Don't be scared just repent. Click on the link I put in my answer.

Comment: Okay thank you soo if i repent will i be forgiven for minor one, i never did major

Comment: You won't be judged for something you didn't do. Allah is Al-Latif, He is the Nice One. Allah will never judge you on major shirk if you didn't commit it. Repent because you commited minor shirk and you will be forgiven.

Comment: So will i be forgiven if i ask for forgiveness and promise not to do it again?

Comment: Yes you will be forgiven, only if you repent sincerely (which means repenting while feeling remorse).

Comment: Okay then thank you soo much brother for everything may Allah grant you and me and everyone Jannah  ( Ameen )